# How to find samba user who writes file?

Tags: linux, samba

I have a zentyal ubuntu system where I get all the time tempory files written into the main share directory. **Is there a way to track down which samba user writes them?**

The files look like that:

```
/path-to-share/t4vc
/path-to-share/t4vc.1
/path-to-share/t4vc.2
/path-to-share/t4f0
/path-to-share/t4f0.1
/path-to-share/t4f0.2
```

I think its a kind of index process but I would like to know from which user machine it comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While posting I found the answer for my question:

I could detect that these files are create by a samba4 process:

```
lsof t4vc*
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
smbd    29545  3000044   67u   REG  252,2  25084928 66289949 t4vc
smbd    29545  3000044   68u   REG  252,2  25084928 66289950 t4vc.1
smbd    29545  3000044   69u   REG  252,2 100339712 66289951 t4vc.2
```

Then you can check our users UID's like that:

```sh
wbinfo --name-to-sid wittich
# S-1-5-21-1002881701-2601196197-2352697156-3105 SID_USER (1)
wbinfo --sid-to-uid S-1-5-21-1002881701-2601196197-2352697156-3105
# 3000044
```

---

*All this leads me to the next question [which Windows process creates these files on the share](https://superuser.com/questions/1080697/wired-files-on-samba4-share-drive-created-by-windows-7-svchost-exe).*