# Strange files on samba4 share drive created by Windows 7 (svchost.exe)

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares

On our samba4 share drive Windows 7 seems to create some strange files. They have the following structure and varies between a few megabytes to over 100 MB:

```
/path-to-share/t4vc
/path-to-share/t4vc.1
/path-to-share/t4vc.2
/path-to-share/t4f0
/path-to-share/t4f0.1
/path-to-share/t4f0.2
```

So far I could track down the Windows 7 user which creates the files and searched with the Process Monitor. Some closer look on the share path shows me some `CreateFile` operations by the `svchost.exe`.

**How can I figure out what does files are for and what the `svchost` process does?**

The Event Properties are showing me the following command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalSystemNetworkRestricted
```

Hast the F-Secure module (fshook64.dll) which is hooked to the process anything to do with it?

[image: event properties]

---

**EDIT**: Here the stack:

```
0   fltmgr.sys  FltAcquirePushLockShared + 0x907    0xfffff88001072067  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
1   fltmgr.sys  FltIsCallbackDataDirty + 0x20ba 0xfffff880010749aa  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
2   fltmgr.sys  FltReadFile + 0x10363   0xfffff880010922a3  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
3   ntoskrnl.exe    MmCreateSection + 0x2d2b    0xfffff800035d2afb  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
4   ntoskrnl.exe    SeQueryInformationToken + 0xe3e 0xfffff800035ce61e  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
5   ntoskrnl.exe    ObOpenObjectByName + 0x306  0xfffff800035cf106  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
6   ntoskrnl.exe    MmCreateSection + 0x112c    0xfffff800035d0efc  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
7   ntoskrnl.exe    NtCreateFile + 0x78 0xfffff800035dc574  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
8   ntoskrnl.exe    KeSynchronizeExecution + 0x3a23 0xfffff800032cf693  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
9   ntdll.dll   NtCreateFile + 0xa  0x777ac08a  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
10  cscsvc.dll  cscsvc.dll + 0x1c53 0x7fefb611c53   c:\windows\system32\cscsvc.dll
11  cscsvc.dll  CscServiceMain + 0x17d21    0x7fefb637999   c:\windows\system32\cscsvc.dll
12  cscsvc.dll  CscServiceMain + 0x2ecc9    0x7fefb64e941   c:\windows\system32\cscsvc.dll
13  RPCRT4.dll  RpcBindingSetAuthInfoW + 0xe5   0x7fefdbce9d5   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
14  RPCRT4.dll  Ndr64AsyncServerCallAll + 0x10ce    0x7fefdc7b54e   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
15  RPCRT4.dll  NdrStubCall3 + 0xc6 0x7fefdbd0e76   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
16  ole32.dll   CoGetInstanceFromFile + 0x4f77  0x7fefda10857   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
17  ole32.dll   CoGetInstanceFromFile + 0x596d  0x7fefda1124d   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
18  ole32.dll   CoGetInstanceFromFile + 0x58e3  0x7fefda111c3   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
19  ole32.dll   CoSetState + 0x1450 0x7fefd8c9d70   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
20  ole32.dll   CoGetInstanceFromFile + 0x5ac6  0x7fefda113a6   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
21  ole32.dll   CoGetInstanceFromFile + 0x59b6  0x7fefda11296   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
22  ole32.dll   CoGetInstanceFromFile + 0x446d  0x7fefda0fd4d   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
23  RPCRT4.dll  NdrServerCall2 + 0x1d74 0x7fefdbc25c4   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
24  RPCRT4.dll  NdrServerCall2 + 0x1bd6 0x7fefdbc2426   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
25  RPCRT4.dll  I_RpcBindingInqTransportType + 0x330    0x7fefdbc4c10   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
26  RPCRT4.dll  I_RpcBindingInqTransportType + 0x26b    0x7fefdbc4b4b   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
27  RPCRT4.dll  I_RpcBindingInqTransportType + 0x202    0x7fefdbc4ae2   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
28  RPCRT4.dll  NdrServerCall2 + 0x1fcd 0x7fefdbc281d   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
29  RPCRT4.dll  I_RpcInitNdrImports + 0x14766   0x7fefdc02dc6   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
30  RPCRT4.dll  I_RpcInitNdrImports + 0x14b60   0x7fefdc031c0   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
31  RPCRT4.dll  NdrServerCall2 + 0x1dab 0x7fefdbc25fb   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
32  RPCRT4.dll  RpcBindingCopy + 0x195  0x7fefdbdef85   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
33  ntdll.dll   TpAlpcRegisterCompletionList + 0x94a    0x777c290a  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
34  ntdll.dll   TpIsTimerSet + 0x455    0x77779d85  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
35  kernel32.dll    BaseThreadInitThunk + 0xd   0x775559bd  C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
36  ntdll.dll   RtlUserThreadStart + 0x21   0x7778a2e1  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```

Comment: look at the stack to see more details

Comment: svhost can be used by any windows or non windows service....http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-svchost-exe#1TC=windows-7

Comment: @magicandre1981 I added the stack...

Comment: cscsvc.dll = Offline Files service. Do you use offline data?

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes I do, the PC is logged into a Domain account, The share drives get automatically connected with the Offline File service.